# Using Lagrange multipliers to identify the Extremes of function $f(x, y)=x-y$, under condition $g(x,y)=x^2 + y^2 - 4=0$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm studying in preparation for a Mathematical Analysis II examination and I'm solving past exam exercises.
*If it's any indicator of difficulty, the exercise is Exercise 3 of 4, part $b$ and graded for 10%.*

> With the Lagrange multiplier method, study the extremes of function $f(x,y)=x-y$ under condition $g(x,y)=x^2 + y^2 - 4 = 0$

I began with noting that $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$ because $f_x= 1,\ f_y= -1,\ g_x = 2x,\ g_y= 2y$ are continuous.

Afterwards, we have: $\nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y)$, which, with the help of the condition $x^2 + y^2 - 4 = 0$, leads us to extreme points $(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ and $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.

Now, how can I study **what** these extremes are? Are they local maximums, local minimums? I know that I'm pretty close and I should use determinants $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$, but for what function, $f$ or $g$? And since $f_{xx} = f_{yy} = 0$, would that lead anywhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In short, you should use Hessian of Lagrangian function. These refererences [(1)](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~clark/285/2006-07/handouts/lagrange-2deriv.pdf) and [(2)](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~chenwb/3b.1.f/lagrange.pdf) might help.

Comment: @Evgeny thanks to the first PDF, I was able to produce a solution. You're the best.

Comment: Do you really have to use Lagrangean multiplyers? Expressed in polar coordinates the result follows straightforwardly.

Comment: The exercise explicitly asks for Lagrange multipliers, I'm afraid. It's for a university course after all. I have another exercise on polar coordinates which I will be posting here shortly, based on my inability to solve it :-P

Comment: The constraint is compact (a circle) and $f$ is continuous, hence it possesses minimum and maximum on the compactum.  Just compare the values of $f$ for the critical points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I was able to come to a seemingly valid solution using Evgeny's help. The reference I used is [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~chenwb/3b.1.f/lagrange.pdf). If you find any mistakes in my process, please point it out or write a correct answer, and I'll accept it instead of my own.

Using the Bordered Hessian matrix: $H = \left[\begin{array}{c}0&g_x&g_y\\g_x&f_{xx}+\lambda g_{xx}&f_{xy}+\lambda g_{xy}
\\g_y & f_{yx} + \lambda g_{yx} & f_{yy}+\lambda g_{yy}\end{array}\right]$

In our exercise, it is written as: $H = \left[\begin{array}{c}0&2x&2y
\\2x&2\lambda & 0
\\2y&0& 2\lambda\end{array}\right]$

We calculate $3\times 3$ ${\rm det}H$ as per the reference document, so it goes: ${\rm det}H = 0+0+0 -2y2\lambda 2y - 2x2x2\lambda$. We know from before, when we found the extreme points, that $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{2x} = \dfrac{-1}{2y}$. Using that, we end up with:

${\rm det}H=4y - 4x$

Finally we calculate ${\rm det}H(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}) = -8\sqrt{2}$ and ${\rm det}H(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) = +8\sqrt{2}$. As the PDF says, since the determinant of the Hessian matrix is negative in the Lagrange critical point $(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ is negative, that extreme is minimum. With the same process, $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ is a maximum because the determinant of the Hessian matrix is positive.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you don't need to use the Bordered Hessian for this question. Your objective function $f(x,y)=x-y$ describes a plane passing orijin and your constraint $x^2 + y^2 =2^2$ is a circle with radius $2$ and center at $(0,0)$. Hence geometrically you have one maximum and one minimum point being symmteric with respect to orijin. You found them as $(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ and $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ by Lagrange method. Now just put them into the function and compare them to which one is maximum and which one is minimum:

$f(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{2} - (-\sqrt{2}) = 2 \sqrt{2}$

$f(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}) = -\sqrt{2} - (\sqrt{2}) = - 2 \sqrt{2}$

Thus, $(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ is the maximum point and $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ is the minimum point.

Please note that here the geometry matters. Your constraint is a circle which is closed and bounded. Also, $g(x,y) \leq 0$ is convex. These simplify many things in general and make geometric interpretations clear. Otherwise, you need some other tools like Bordered Hessian as @Evgeny suggested.